# Node JS Request module not getting the tab response

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get response for url `http://teespring.com/dashboard/campaigns#tab-get-paid` but it always comes back with content of `http://teespring.com/dashboard/campaigns`.

Flow is like this.

1. User go to the page `http://teespring.com/dashboard/campaigns`
2. Page has 4 tabs. User click on one of the tab. Browser shows url `http://teespring.com/dashboard/campaigns#tab-get-paid`.

I am assuming that may be the page is getting generated dynamically.
 If this is the case then how would get the desired response.

Comment: How do you route the url and render the response in your Node backend? Pls share some code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hash fragment identifiers are not sent to the server. It's only used in the browser.

If you are seeing different content for the #hash, it is rendered by client-side script. So you cannot scrape by traditional method.

Comment: How can I scrape then?

Comment: You need to know how the page content is updated. Monitor the page with Browser debug tools (Web Inspector or Firebug) to find out more how the page is rendered. For example, if the page content is loaded via ajax on hashchange, you could fetch the content from ajax url ... 

Also find out if the site supports 'shebang' - google crawling. If it does you could duplicate what google does. More Info on [google crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) SPAs.